# If user log in again, how to redirect the user to the last page he visited in his last session in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am developing a website using django, and I want to redirect a user to the last page he was at during his last session before log out when he log in again.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, you use the next parameter to redirect to the page you want. this is how it might work. In your template add this `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}"/>`, then after successful authentication, retrieve the variable in the view like so:

next_page = request.POST.get('next')

if next_page:
return redirect(next_page)

this will redirect to the desired page